# Android gallery with bigs images for zoom

Tags: android, memory, gallery, zooming

I try to implement a Gallery where each item is a big image for a good zomm-in function. 
The problem is the management of the memory. 
When i try to go to the fourth element android goes to Out Of Memory, so i try to recycle the images not displayed, but android goes to RunTimeException for try to use a recycled image when i come back.
Also i try to change the bitmap of the bigs images not displayed with bitmap of small images but always goes to Out Of Memory.

How can i do, for manage the memory of the Gallery?

Answer (score 0):

After you do call [recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29), make sure you don't use that Bitmap reference again as that will cause a runtime exception if certain methods are invoked. Try using [SoftReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html)s wrapped around your bitmaps. This will guarantee that all of the memory that is no longer references will be reclaimed before an OutOfMemoryError is thrown.